# Implementing vanity URL for individual users in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, member

How would one go about implementing a vanity URL for each user in PHP? I'm implementing my web-app's login system as a tweaked version of the Drax LLP Login system.

So, each user should be able to modify his profile which will finally appear on his vanity URL .. like xyz.com/user.

Any tips / ideas? Thanks..

Comment: vanity URL would be user.xyz.com, not xyz.com/user :) Well, simple mod_rewrite rule, if available, will do the trick

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion :) . Yeah I'm looking for something like xyz.com/user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the files involved:

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
function getWebPath() {
    $location = "";

    // Read the relative URL into an array
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'])) { // IIS Rewrite
        $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
    } elseif(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { // Apache
        $location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    } elseif(isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) { // Apache mod_rewrite (breaks on CGI)
        $location = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    } elseif(isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'])) { // IIS + CGI
        $location = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
    }

    return $location;
}

$location = getWebPath();

print_r($location);
```

The function above should become a method in your front controller class somewhere.  You just need to subtract your base path from $location so you're left with the virtual path.  Then you can do whatever you want -- e.g. simply split on '/' and then work your way through the path, passing each remainder to the next controller depending on the URI.  You could also write more complicated routing rules using regular expressions (something Django and quite a few other frameworks do).

For example:
/profiles/hardik988

Would be passed to the controller in charge of 'profiles', which then decides what to do with the remainder of the path.  It would likely look up the username and display the appropriate template.

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively simple: you have a `mod_rewrite` rule to map requests to `www.domain.com/username` to something like `www.domain.com/users/username`.

However, you then need to be aware what to prohibit from being a username, as I presume you'll have other top-level pages such as `www.domain.com/about` or `www.domain.com/terms`. Therefore, you don't want people registering `about` and `terms` as usernames.

Comment: OK I'll take a look into that :) I'm new to PHP and still delving through the manual.. Thanks. Also, thanks for the tip on the exception of usernames :)

Comment: One method you could use is when a user is registering a user name, to check with `cURL` or similar whether that URL already exists (`200 OK`). If so, deny them the ability to register it.

Comment: The cURL trick is clever, and certainly efficient if the frontend doesn't have easy access to the data store (e.g. preparing to send a request to a web service).