# I want to assign each user a unique URL - PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm going to develop a social network website, I want to assign each user a unique URL address Like facebook but I don not know how can I do it with PHP.

Answer (score 5):

You could setup [wildcard DNS](http://ma.tt/2003/10/wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains/) and make each user have his/her subdomain: http://username.domain.com

Or you could use the [mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776315/implementing-vanity-url-for-individual-users-in-php) with Apache and rewrite a url pattern that would look similar to facebook's vanity usernames: http://domain.com/username

Answer (score 4):

lets say that you have a php system which can show the profile of a user like this

```
domain.com/user.php?username=foobar
```

now using url_rewriting using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule username/(.*)/ user.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule username/(.*) user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

this will give something like

```
domain.com/username/foobar
```

and to make them unique like fb, just make sure to track all the current names in use and dont allow users to register with the names already used.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easly achieved by using Zend Router:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html